# Questions about site concept in eclipses (and iviewsite in particular)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, concept

1) Can somebody please explain what a site is? I can't seem to find a proper definition of this term anywhere.

2) What is the purpose of the IViewSite interface?. It does not have any children (class or interface, as specified in the docs. This interface is not supposed to be extended. why define those two methods if there isn't a single class that implements them?

What is the purpose of an IViewSite variable since that variable will not have any properties and it has only pure virtual methods? There's no point in adapting to it either.

I already looked through the docs but I can 't seem to find a concrete explanation.

Ok upon further documenting I think I may have found out what a site is:

> an object that gets associated with a workbench part (view or editor)
>   by means of the init() method

But what exactly happens to that reference of the site? I dont know since Viewpart for example does not have a property that stores the reference to the site object. If anyone has a link to a diagram or something it would be much appreciated.

LE: Is the reference to the site object stored in some kind of register along with the reference to the object that

LE2 www@eclipsezone@com/eclipse/forums/t92910.html
" The IViewPart.init method is called to initialize the context for the view. An IViewSite object is passed, and contains methods to get the containing page, window, and other services is passed. " What is the use since there is no implementing class?..

Comment: Come on people, a little help here?

Answer (score 1):

There **is** an implementing class, it's just not within scope of your Java Search (nor found during the JavaDoc generation, but nevertheless it exists).  You could also ask in the forums at eclipse.org itself.